# Phone Discharging When Connected to Laptop

Tags: laptop, usb, battery, phone, windows-phone

I have got a Microsoft Lumia 532 which keeps discharging at a greater rate than normal when connected to my laptop (Dell XPS L502X) using a USB cable, instead of charging. I am not really sure about the USB version of the cable (2.0 or 3.0).

Situation Specifics:

- Laptop: Dell XPS L502X (Windows 7)
- Phone: Microsoft Lumia 532 (Windows Phone 8.1)
- Phone is connected to my laptop using a USB cable
- Laptop is always connected to a power source (Laptop battery died 2 years back)
- The phone was charging perfectly under the same conditions until 1 week back

Troubleshooting Tried:

- Rebooting the laptop
- Restarting the phone
- Phone is up-to-date with the software
- Latest drivers are in place for the laptop

Comment: Does it charge if you turn it off or when you connect it to another power source?

Comment: Yes, it does when I directly connect it to a power source using the dedicated phone charger.

Comment: And does it charge if powered off and connected to the computer?

Comment: No, it does not.
Looks like it might be a problem with my USB cable itself.
What I don't understand is, why would it discharge at a faster rate than normal when connected to laptop?

Comment: If the connection is shorted, it would do that.  Try a different port or cable to clarify the issue.

Comment: Different port? Yes, I have tried it. Same issue.
Different cable? Procedure pending. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Sometimes such unexpected behaviour can occur on the software side. Have you tried resetting your phone to default settings and see if the problem remains?

Comment: Bit too late to the party, I suppose. Anyway, it wasn't a software issue @alljamin. It was the charging pin issue, folks. It's fixed now. Thanks for all of your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The phone is discharging its internal battery because it did not find proper charging signature at the end of USB cable you are using. It likely is taking only minimal current (100mA or 500mA), which is not enough to maintain the phone functional state, so it uses internal battery.

The 532 phone uses small u-USB port, which means it is USB2 only.

Which signature is expected by your 532 phone, I don't know. You can reverse engineer the cable end on the wall charger that comes with the phone. It is very likely that it uses "Chinese" charger signature, where D+ is shorted with D-. If so, you can make a "special" charging cable by opening up the USB cable's cover and shield, cut green/white wires, and tie them together at the end which goes to phone.

Comment: That is a poor assumption since OP seems to indicate that it discharges faster than it charges which implies that it does charge.  Without more details, this answer is at **most** an unlikely explanation.

Comment: Your concern does not make much sense. How do you know if it charges at all? The OP statement is, "it  keeps discharging at a greater rate than normal", which implies that it is not charging itself a all, but continues to discharge its internal battery even when connected to USB port. I would guess that it discharges faster than normal (I assume when not connected) because the phone probably maintains some USB connected state which drains additional current. I have 99% confidence in my explanation, I have spent last 3 years dealing with this kind of issues.

Comment: Apologies. I forgot to mention that the phone was charging perfectly with USB cable connected to my laptop, until 1 week back. I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Which port you are using? Your laptop has two ports, one Universal USB  / external SATA, and the other is USB3 (blue), right? You can have dirty pins, oxidized pins, bent pins in your cable, etc.  Did you try to use a different (new) USB cable? Still it looks like the phone does not recognize any charging signature.

Comment: Yes, I have tried all the ports. The issue is the same.
Trying out a new cable still needs to be done though.
Anyway, thanks for your help!